# Mystery 403 Error

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-403

I have a PHP page (one of many) that is used to display and update the content of a mySQL database. The page is constructed in a very straightforward way: clicking the Submit button reloads the page, a PHP routine updates the datasbase and the page is displayed again with the new content.

Suddenly today I hit a problem with it. On first opening, the page is fine but after clicking the submit button I get a 403 error. This error pops up before the PHP has been run because the database is not updated.

Other similar pages don't have the same problem so I worked through the file taking bits out until the problem went away. The conclusion was that two of the form inputs (out of about 20 in total) are causing the problem. The code for one of those problem inputs is

```
<tr class="formspace">
<td valign="top" class="formleft"><br>
<br>
From the Hotel Guestbook</td>
<td colspan="2"><textarea name="guestbook" cols="60" rows="4" wrap="VIRTUAL" id="guestbook"><?php echo $row_hotel['guestbook']; ?></textarea>
<span class="formnote">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remember to put &lt;hr class="guestbook"&gt; between the paras.</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Yet this one doesn't cause a problem

```
<tr class="formspace">
<td valign="top" class="formleft"><br>
<br>
Restaurant</td>
<td colspan="2"><textarea name="restaurant" cols="60" rows="4" wrap="VIRTUAL" id="restaurant"><?php echo $row_hotel['restaurant']; ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

The two problem name fields are "guestbook" and "activities", which seem pretty inoccuous and shouldn't conflict with anything else.

Permissions for the file are just the same as everything else that does work. 644 on the file and 755 on the folder it is in.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: can we see all the code?

Comment: The code you supplied seems irrelevant to the problem. Problem lies somewhere else in the code so please post more

Comment: Yes the code was irrelevant, but I didn't know that at the time. See my comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered similar problems before, and if this is the same problem, your webhost has installed mod_security, or has changed the filter settings.

What mod_security does (among others) is filtering all request variables (POST, GET, etc.). It checks for common hacky sql injection strings (like `"; DELETE * FROM`x`WHERE 1`), but also strings that are used commonly for hacks, and guestbook and activities sound like strings that could be filtered.

You can turn the mod_security off by adding these lines in your .htaccess:

```
SecFilterEngine Off
```

Or, to just turn it off for POST requests:

```
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

**EDIT** a better way is to wrap it inside a `<IfModule ...>` statement:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried turning it off in .htaccess but it broke everything. I had to quickly back out of that without a detailed investigation.
I've contacted our hosting company to see if they know anything about it.

Comment: Everything is quite a lot ;) try the statements below the edit, that should at least not break anything. Btw you don't have to worry that much. If something goes wrong it just doesn't work, but it doesn't break, like breaking a glass.

Comment: I contacted our webhosts (Clook, they're the Best) and they disabled a few mod_sec rules. Everything is now looking good.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, giorgio.